# Creating array to compare custom field values

Tags: wp-query, loop, advanced-custom-fields

I think I need some guidance here. 
I have a list of custom posts on a an archive template page that displays information from each of the custom posts. They are looped through using WPQuery:

```
<?php $restypes = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'reservation_type', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );?>
```

Each post has a several custom fields: `$price`, an optional `$promo_price` and a variable `$per` which determines if the price is per-person or per-room based on a custom taxonomy. The best price is then determined like so:

```
  if(in_array( 'dorm', $per )){
      $person_room ='per-person';
  } else {
      $person_room ='per-room';
  }  

  $post_id= $post->ID;
  $promo_price = get_field('promo_price');
  $norm_price = get_field('price');
  $p_per_room = get_field('people_per_room');

  if ($promo_price && !empty($promo_price)){

        if($person_room == 'per-room'){
            $addprice= $promo_price /$p_per_room;
        } else {
            $addprice= $promo_price;
        }

        $prices[$post_id]= $addprice;

  } elseif ($norm_price && !empty($norm_price)){

        if($person_room == 'per-room'){
            $addprice= $norm_price /$p_per_room;
        } else {
            $addprice= $norm_price;
        }

        $prices[$post_id]= $addprice;
  }

  $best = array_keys($prices, min($prices));
```

My problem is that the array `$best` is not complete until all the posts have been looped through. The point of all this is to be able to add:

```
<?php
if(in_array($post->ID, $best)){?> 
<div class="best-price"> 
<div class="ribbon-wrapper"><div class="ribbon">Best Price</div></div>
<?php  } else { ?>
    <div>
<?php } ?>
```

thus giving a different style to the item with the best price per-person.

My question is would I need to create a separate loop to populate the `$best` array in order to do this? Or is there a better way?

I was thinking initially of using the `orderby => 'meta_value_num'` having calculated the best price as a function and adding a meta value.

PS The `get_field()` function comes from Advanced custom fields.

Answer (score 0):

Well i see only two ways either you have to have seprate loop to get best value or you can add ribbon wrapper by using css and absolute positioning of div setting top and left. Though it would be best if you can calculate best value using meta_value_num.

Comment: So I would get and calculate all values in the first loop and use the second to display them? The ribbon is positioned fine I just need to calculate which post(s) to apply it to. If I use `orderby` I could simply style the first post listed but that wouldn't help if there were several with the same price per-person.

Comment: "...best if you can calculate best value using `meta_value_num`..."-- How?

Comment: @s_ha_dum to be honest i don't see any possibilities other than have two loops one for calculating best and than one for displaying. He can achive it using one loop with jquery by keeping best value in hidden field and then use jquery to fetch that data and display particular ribbon based on ids

Comment: Then why suggest calculating via `meta_value_num`?

Comment: @s_ha_dum "calculating via meta_value_num?" was asked in question as sugestion, so if he can calculate that would be best option.

Comment: I ended up using 2 loops. Thanks @RajeevVyas for your input but I don't feel your answer really answers the question: "would I need to create a separate loop to populate the $best array in order to do this? Or is there a better way?"